# WMS 1.3.0 invalid-format test failed even with proper/required code returned

Tags: wms

I got the following test failed, though it looks that WMS 1.3.0 server responded with proper error code. See below:

---

```
Test Name:invalid-formatTest 
Description:When a GetMap request contains a Format that is not advertised, then the server throws a Service Exception (code=InvalidFormat).Test Result:FAILEDTest Requests 1:
Method: GET
URL:    http://<host>:7003/mapviewer/wms?FoRmAt=UnknownFormat&VeRsIoN=1.3.0&LaYeRs=WMS_BASICPOLYGONS&CrS=CRS%3A84&BbOx=-0.0025,-0.0025,0.0025,0.0025&HeIgHt=100&ReQuEsT=GetMap&WiDtH=100&StYlEs=

Outputs:    ?

    <cnt:rest><response xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
         <parser local-name="HTTPParser" namespace-uri="http://www.occamlab.com/te/parsers" prefix="parsers"/>
         <content>
            <response>
               <status code="200" protocol="HTTP/1.1">OK</status>
               <headers>
                  <header name="Date">Thu, 11 Mar 2021 15:29:30 GMT</header>
                  <header name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</header>
                  <header name="Content-Type">text/xml;charset=UTF-8</header>
                  <header name="X-FRAME-OPTION">SAMEORIGIN</header>
                  <header name="X-CSRF-Token-MVS">7040519b275824a90951f6bad613ae83b836a7c333932294</header>
                  <header name="X-XSS-Protection">1</header>
                  <header name="Set-Cookie">X-CSRF-MVS=7040519b275824a90951f6bad613ae83b836a7c333932294; Path=/mapviewer; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict</header>
               </headers>
               <content>
                  <ServiceExceptionReport xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
                     <ServiceException code="InvalidFormat">[wms] invalid FORMAT parameter.</ServiceException>
                  </ServiceExceptionReport>
               </content>
               <!--Response received in [62] milliseconds--></response>
         </content>
      </response></cnt:rest>

Reason of Failure:
```

---

Do you see any hints that failed the test?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what tests are you running?

Comment: 1/2: The test name is: "Test Name:invalid-formatTest".
2/2: The test url is: "http://<host>:7003/mapviewer/wms?FoRmAt=UnknownFormat&VeRsIoN=1.3.0&LaYeRs=WMS_BASICPOLYGONS&CrS=CRS%3A84&BbOx=-0.0025,-0.0025,0.0025,0.0025&HeIgHt=100&ReQuEsT=GetMap&WiDtH=100&StYlEs="

Comment: Is this a well known test suite or one you wrote yourself?

Comment: It comes from the test result page at OGC test site(i.e., https://cite.opengeospatial.org/teamengine/viewSessions.jsp). Steps I took: I log onto my account; run my test after providing my server instance url and choosing test options. After the run, I go to the result page): getmap>format>invalid-format. For example, this failed test case url is: https://cite.opengeospatial.org/teamengine/reports/honglzhu/s0005/result/invalid-format2929292929.html#invalid-format2929292929

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to update your question